# CSV All delimiters

Tags: php, excel, csv

I want to know the delimiters exists for a .CSV file? Because I saw exist comma, but exist and semicolon and I need all delimiters for an php script.

Comment: Did you try anything already? Can we see it? Also you have to know what the delimiters are upfront, or do some strong checking on the content of the CSV file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There is no real "CSV standard"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Lack_of_a_standard), so in theory, any character can be used as a delimiter.

The most common ones are `,` (especially in the US), `;` (especially in Europe because we need the comma as a decimal separator), `\t` (tab, ASCII `0x09`) and `|`. Usually, whitespace around the delimiters is not part of the delimiter, but even that can be changed.

This is why good implementations offer a [CSV sniffer](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Sniffer) that tries to guess the format of any given CSV file.